Не загружается страница
Не загружается страница react. По началу идет быстрая загрузка потом бац и все, очень медленно начинает идти и по окончанию загрузки нечего не происходит(белый экран) исходный код. Как это можно исправить и из за чего это может происходить? 

Тут только дебажить приложение. Похоже у вас какойто бесконечный цикл чего то перегружает браузер и он падает

Я тоже так думал, но оказалось все куда проще. Я в файле Button.jsx создавал кнопку и за место  написал  и из за этого не работало.

Я в файле Button.jsx создавал кнопку и вместо <button/> написал <Button/>, и из!за этого не работало.
Заметил я это после прочтения этой статьи.
